# Finding label of a property

Tags: sparql

I am trying to find label of a property on dbpedia with this query

```
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
SELECT
    ?label
WHERE {
    geo:lat rdfs:label ?label.
} LIMIT 20
```

But it does not return anything. I've checked wgs84 ontology, and `lat` has the label `latitutde`. Why doesn't it work, and how would I go about finding properties labels in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've checked wgs84 ontology, and lat has the label latitutde [sic].

That doesn't mean that DBpedia includes all the triples that that ontology specifies.  If DBpedia doesn't include that data, then you'd need to look for it in places where it **is** available.  DBpedia doesn't include any triples with **geo:lat** as subject or object, as shown by the zero results to this query:

```
select * where {
  { geo:lat ?p ?o }
  union 
  { ?s ?p geo:lat }
}
```

DBpedia just happens to include triples where **geo:lat** is used as a predicate.  For more information about the predicate, you'll have to look to where it's defined.

Comment: Thank you. I was afraid I formulated query incorrect.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, you are not _absolutely_ correct! See [this query](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=select+%3Fg+%3Fs+%3Fp+%3Fo+where%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%7B%0D%0Avalues+%28%3Fs%29%7B%28geo%3Alat%29%7D%0D%0Agraph+%3Fg+%7B%3Fs+%3Fp+%3Fo+%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aunion%0D%0A%7B%0D%0Avalues+%28%3Fo%29%7B%28geo%3Alat%29%7D%0D%0Agraph+%3Fg+%7B%3Fs+%3Fp+%3Fo%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on). There is also a strange entity named [dbo:geo:lat](http://mappings.dbpedia.org/index.php/OntologyProperty:Geo:lat)...